# Write-ahead-logging (WAL) used in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to do some work with Write-ahead-logging(WAL) on Postgres. Could anyone point me to the WAL implementation in Postgres codebase? I just want to know current implementation and start to modify that. Any version of Postgres is fine unless it has WAL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, what "work" do you want to do with the transaction logging?

Comment: You seem to have also posted this to pgsql-hackers: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEHyd7f_V9GdEXCFkvkfsnfRErrxh67CVKJFxAeWhvhpSawjjA@mail.gmail.com  . If you're going to do that, please link from one to the other so people don't waste time with duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the code is here:

```
src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c
```

And:

```
src/backend/access/transam/README
```

But of course the need to do WAL permeates the entire code base.

You have picked perhaps the most difficult possible starting point to get your feet wet.  (I should know--that is also how I did it).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know it's that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

WAL is write-ahead logging. Basically, before the database actually
performs an operation, it writes in a log what it's about to do. Then, it
goes and does it. This ensures data consistency. Let's say that the
computer was powered off suddenly. There are several points that could
happen:
1) before a write - in this case the database would be fine with or
without write-ahead logging.

2) during a write - without write-ahead logging, if the machine is powered
off during a write, the database has no way of knowing what remained to be
written, or what was being written. WIth Postgres, this is furthere
broken down into two possibilities:

- The power-off occurred while it was writing to the log - in this
  case, the log is rolled back. The database is unaffected because the data
  was never written to the database proper.
- The power-off occurred after writing to the log, while writing to
  disk - in this case, Postgres can simply read from the log what was
  supposed to be written, and complete the write.

3) after a write - again, this does not affect Postgres either with or
without WAL.

In addition, WAL increases PostgreSQL's efficiency, because it can delay
random-access writes to disk, and just do sequential writes to the log for
a long time. This reduces the amount of head-seek the dissk are doing.
If you store your WAL files on a different disk, you get even more speed
advantages.